# Prepared statement as sql parameter

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

How could I pass the question mark of a prepared statement into a sql LIKE statement?

LIKE '&?&' but the question mark would be the passed parameter from the prepared statement.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Your title suggests that you want to pass a prepared statement as the value of a parameter: that is not possible. If not, you might want to consider rephrasing your question a bit.

Comment: Changing the ampersands to percentage signs would be a good start.

Comment: Working with Java and Oracle DB. And yes, I realize they are supposed to be %. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an expression.  For instance in ANSI SQL:

```
where col like '%' || ? || '%'
```

Some databases use `concat()` or `+`, instead of (or in addition to) `||`.

Comment: Instead of using DBMS-specific concatenation syntax, do it in the [Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50218173/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the Java code, instead of in the SQL.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, "%" + value + "%");
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        // code here
    }
}
```